# Is there any way to start automatically the Firebug/Inspector after starting Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug

is there any way to start automatically the Inspector after starting Chrome?

is there any way to start automatically the Firebug after starting Firefox?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Firefox you can set Firebug to be always on by opening ***about:config*** and setting `extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation` to `on`.

Note that this will have Firebug always active and recording -- which you can see by the Firebug icon being colored -- but the panel may be minimized.   Show it by clicking the icon or using the hotkey (Usually <kbd>F12</kbd> but sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>).

Note that the valid values for `extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation` are:

- **none** --  (default) Page-by-page settings may apply.
- **on**     --  Firebug is activated for all URLs.
- **off**     --  Firebug is never activated.

Comment: Good answer, I did not know about the kbd tag

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have been searching it is not possible to do that in Google Chrome. But you can use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to open it immediately. Hope it helps!