# Enable Firefox DevTools on new opened tabs by default (if they were enabled before)

Tags: mozilla, firefox-developer-tools

Earlier, when I was using Firebug and opened new tab - Firebug was already activated there. Now, in Firefox 51.0.1, I need to press <kbd>F12</kbd> every time to open the Firefox DevTools. How can I activate them by default for new tabs?

The [allPagesActivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127776/is-there-any-way-to-start-automatically-the-firebug-inspector-after-starting-fir) option in *about:config* doesn't help.

Comment: There is no option for that atm, maybe you should try to request this feature @ [Bugzilla@Mozilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: Mehdi Dehghani, Ok, thank You, I've done it

Comment: For reference, @GennadyG created [bug 1336405](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1336405), which I closed as duplicate of [bug 1284012](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1284012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firebug's activation model](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Activation) is URL based following the same origin policy, by default. It can be changed to be always on via the `extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation` property, as you already noted.

The DevTools' activation model, though, is tab based and there is no option yet to change that (as of Firefox 51.0.1). Though this is already requested in [bug 1284012](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1284012).

Comment: I'm also hoping for this option to be added, two years later.